# Salesforce Metadata Components API for hybrid applications.

Tags: metadata-api, html5, salesforcetouchplatform, jquerymobile

Is there any way to fetch metadata components of salesforce for hybrid applications using jquery-mobile,html5 and phonegap.

I want to fetch Flow(Salesforce Metadata Component) in my hybrid application running on iPhone and Android devices.

Please help me. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a REST version of the Metadata API. There was a pilot to expose a REST version, but I don't think it has made it to GA (General Availability) yet.

One option would be to create your own web service that can accept the JSON calls from your app and then relay them on as SOAP messages to the existing Metadata API. It would need to reverse the process for the response.

See the Metadata API Documentation for the [Flow](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_visual_workflow.htm) object.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

I think this link should help you out in understanding. But recently salesforce hosted all the metadata components as the Rest API service on the same server where the application is running. Now you can directly call Rest API for the component/salesforce Object from the javascript/jquery and access the data. But this involves the API calls where as above link doesnot include any api call.

I hope this clears your question

Comment: Try this link for my second suggested solution http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/06/calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-visualforce-pages-revisited.html

Comment: Mukul its not worthful for me, please send me some other link so that I fulfill my task.

Comment: Sorry Ila I have misunderstood your original question.

Comment: I have create two Flows in my salesforce portal, now I need to fetch these flows in my device(android as well as iPhone) for hybrid application using jquery mobile. And I dont want to use Visualforce code as mention in above link.